# structuremap bootstrap in class library / dll

Tags: structuremap

What is the best approach to bootstrap a dll using structuremap?  I don't really want the consumers of the library to have to configure anything themselves if they don't want to.  I am thinking that the .config would likely be the simplest, but then again 2.6.1 is out and I am not familiar with many of its features / changes yet.

Comment: Does your library have a common entry point or initialization? Worse case scenario you could use a static initializer which bootstraps StructureMap.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't really a common entry point.  The classes have constructors, but that seems hardly the place to handle it.  Can you explain the static initializer?  do you mean just check a static param indicating initialization in the ctors?

Comment: If your library is using DI and needs StructureMap configured you need a point at where the consumer of your library first touches your library to spin up the StructureMap container. Maybe you could use a factory method as a way for API users to construct objects and simultaneously make sure the contaiiner is configured. Ignore the static initializer they are evil. I was sniffing glue.

Comment: I think the factory sounds like a good approach.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you could use a factory method to ensure that the StructureMap container is spun up and ready to go for top level classes in your library. Here is an example.

```
public interface ILibraryClass
{
    void SomethingAwesome();
}

public class LibraryClass : ILibraryClass
{
    public void SomethingAwesome()
    {
    }
}

public class API
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    private static IContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
          if (_container == null) //TODO add locking around this for thread safety?
             InitializeContainer();

          return _container;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer()
    {
        _container = new Container(config => { config.For<ILibraryClass>().Use<LibraryClass>(); });
    }

    public static ILibraryClass LibraryClass()
    {
        return Container.GetInstance<ILibraryClass>();
    }
 }

[Test]
public void library_factory_method()
{
    API.LibraryClass().ShouldBeOfType<LibraryClass>();
}
```